# Network object and adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, adjacency-matrix

I have a proximity network which contains the following information:

Abigail lives close to Frank

Abigail lives close to Cameron

Billy lives close to Daniell

Ethan lives close to Cameron

Ethan lives close to Frank

Frank lives close to Cameron

Could someone please help me with the code to make this into an adjacency matrix, with a vertex.names node attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data as you have it is basically an edge list. You can use `igraph` to turn that into a graph and then turn it into an adjacency matrix.

```
EL = as.matrix(read.table(text="
Abigail Frank
Abigail Cameron
Billy Daniell
Ethan Cameron
Ethan Frank
Frank Cameron"))

library(igraph)

g = graph_from_edgelist(EL, directed = FALSE)
as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(g))

        Abigail Frank Cameron Billy Daniell Ethan
Abigail       0     1       1     0       0     0
Frank         1     0       1     0       0     1
Cameron       1     1       0     0       0     1
Billy         0     0       0     0       1     0
Daniell       0     0       0     1       0     0
Ethan         0     1       1     0       0     0
```

Comment: how do i do: vertex.names node